# Is there mdbg for dotnet3.5?

Tags: c#, debugging

There is a server which support 3.5 and not installed visual studio, and I also have a program based on 3.5. I wanna copy a mdbg for 3.5 to the server for debugging. Where can I find it?

I found mdbg in VS8.0(for dotnet2.0) and VS10.0(for dotnet4.0), but not found in VS9.0(for dotnet3.5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MDbg ([.NET Framework Command-Line Debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229861%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)) is the same for .NET 2.0 and .NET 3.5 as .NET 3.5 is just an extension of .NET 2.0.  So, if your project has targeted .NET 3.5, you can still use the MDbg found in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC`.

Comment: Are you meanning that the identical mdbg support 2.0 3.5 4.0 without difference?

Comment: I'm saying that the version you need to run for .NET 2.0 and .NET 3.5 is basically the .NET 2.0 version.  The .NET 4.0 version is different because .NET 4.0 is a completely new version of .NET whereas .NET 3.5 is just an add-on to .NET 2.0.